# OpenVPN Server Site-to-Site and RoadWarrior access

Tags: vpn, openvpn, site-to-site-vpn

I have a main office with a network 192.168.40.0/24 and a subsidiary office that have a network with this address 192.168.1.0/24, i want to link this office :

Allow PC on the main office to access PC in the subsidiary and PC in subsidiary office to access PC on main office; in addition i want to allow some roadwarrior user to connect to main office Network with their notebook.

I want to use OpenVPN, and in subsidiary office i have a router with DD-WRT on board that theorically can connect to VPN Server on main office and distribute connection to each client.

What's the best way to implement a similar VPN?

Do i need to setup a routed or a bridged VPN ?

How to configure VPN serveR ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up an OpenVPN server in the main office in client/server mode using x509 certificates and using the 'client-config-dir' option. Place a client-config file for the dd-wrt router in the client-config-dir directory

Configure the dd-wrt to connect as a regular client, but make sure to use a fixed IP and using an 'iroute' statement to tell the openvpn server that the network 192.168.1.0/24 is behind the dd-wrt "client".

The road warriors can connect as regular clients to the OpenVPN server.

Most of this is explained in the OpenVPN HOWTO pages, especially the part 'expanding the scope' for information on the ccd-file and 'iroute' statements.

HTH,

JJK